# Django Unit Testing That Needs OAuth Authentication

Tags: django, python-3.x, unit-testing, python-unittest, django-testing

I have a Django project that uses Gmail API to send bulk emails. Users can create campaign emails and send them to multiple contacts. If a contact answer to any of the emails in a campaign then that contact should no longer receive emails from that campaign email.

I want to add unit tests for this feature and I don't know what approach to use because I need to authorize one Gmail account first and only after that use that account to send the campaign email. Also I would like to test the replies of that campaign, which means that I need to authorize a new Gmail account that will be used to send the reply.

So this is what I plan to do:
1. Authorize two Gmail accounts manually.
2. Inside the tests I will search for the first two Gmail accounts from the database and use one of them to send the campaign email and another one to reply to an email.

The only problem is that I am not sure that this approach is the best, this is why I am asking here, maybe someone has a better idea.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You also can write accounts authorization code in `unittest.TestCase.setUp(self)` method. [It will be called right before each of your test methods](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.setUp). Considering OAuth usage, I strongly recommend to you to use [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) package. It's quite handy in any API testing and stuff.

Comment: The problem is that the accounts are using external API's (Gmail and Outlook) and I have no way to authorise them.